# Why ListView.ItemSource come null when using MessagingCenter to pass data from database from iOS project to MainPage - Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I want to pass the list with data from database from iOS project to main page (Main Project) and want to fill `ListView` using `MessagingCenter`

**From iOS project in `CustomMapRenderer.cs` I use this method to send data to main page in the main project:**

```
CustomPin GetCustomPin(MKPointAnnotation annotation)
    {
        var position = new Position(annotation.Coordinate.Latitude, annotation.Coordinate.Longitude);

        foreach (var pin in customPins)
        {
            if (pin.Position == position)
            {
                int mapCode = int.Parse(pin.CodeNum.ToString());

                var result = DataBaseConnection(mapCode);

                MessagingCenter.Send<object, IEnumerable<AlertLevel>>(this, "PinSelected", result);

                return pin;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**And `result` is filled with data:**

[image: result]

**In the `MainPage.cs` I try to receive the data with this code:**

```
 public void MarkerPressed()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, IEnumerable<AlertLevel>>(this, "PinSelected", (sender, arg) =>
        {
            lstLevel.ItemsSource = arg;

            labelColumn1.IsVisible = true;
            labelColumn2.IsVisible = true;
            labelColumn3.IsVisible = true;
            content.IsVisible = false;
        });
    }
```

**But `lstLevel.ItemsSource = arg;` come null and I don't know why ?**

**My `ListView` in `MainPage.xaml` is:**

```
<ListView x:Name="lstLevel">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                       Text="{Binding dateForecast, StringFormat='{0:dd.MM} - {0:hh\\:mmч.}'}"/>
                                <Image Source="{Binding levelForecast, Converter={StaticResource levelImage}}"
                                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                 <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                       Text="{Binding levelForecast}"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                               
                            </StackLayout>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

**This way work fine on `Android` project but in iOS I don't know why `arg` on `ListView` come null ?**

**How to pass the data from iOS project to my `ListView` in `MainPage`** ?

Comment: According to your code, I tried to restore sending an IEnumerable<> in ios to MainPage.cs by using MessagingCenter. As a result, I successfully received the value sent in ios in MainPage.cs. I hope you can provide some information about AlertLevel

Comment: I list has been empty, now everything work fine ! thank you